# LoadLibrary is not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have created an `*.exe` and `*.dll` for my project.
I have provided all the correct path and data.
`Myexe.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HMODULE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary(L("..\\Debug\\LoadDLL\\LoadDLL.dll"));// I have checked with complete path as well.
    if(hInstLibrary)
    {
        printf("Hello World");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`MyDLL.cpp`:

```
#include "MyDLL.h"
#include <stdio.h>

    MyDLL::MyDLL(void)
    {

}


MyDLL::~MyDLL(void)
{
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld()
{
    printf("Hello DLL");
}
```

`MyDLL.h`:

```
#pragma once
class __declspec(dllexport) MyDLL
{
public:
    MyDLL(void);
    ~MyDLL(void);
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void HelloWorld();
```

I have tried providing the `complete path` also. But it is still failing. The `hInstLibrary` is setting to `0x00000`. I tried in `Release mode` too but the problem still lies there.
But when I have tried with:

```
HMODULE hInstLibrary = LoadLibrary(_T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\aeinv.dll"));
```

it does load the `DLL`. So, please help me where is it going wrong. The DLL gets build properly, there is absolutely no error in building DLL. Then why am I facing this problem??

Is there any setting need to be done for `Debug`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) to find out what went wrong.

Edit:

You got 0x7e, which means:

> **ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND**
>
> 126 (0x7E)
>
> The specified module could not be found.

Your path is wrong. You need to fix that.

Comment: When I have `wprintf(L"Format message failed with 0x%x\n", GetLastError());`. It prints `Format message failed with 0x7e`

Comment: When I have taken `LPCSTR str = "..\\Debug\\LoadDLL\\LoadDLL.dll"` the passed the `str` into `LoadLibrary` then it did work. So, where exactly was it going wrong?

Comment: You probably used unicode when your project was compiled for non-unicode, although that would have generated warnings. If you want to chose later if your program uses unicode, you can use the _T macros as described in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

Inspect your executable with [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/faq.html) and the profile it from there. You'll get a better picture as to why your dll fails to load and how the dependency tree looks like.

When you start profiling (F7) make sure that 'Log LoadLibrary function calls' is checked.

You can also check [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see if anything is applicable to your specific case.

Answer (score 3):

What's `L` in `L("..\\Debug\\LoadDLL\\LoadDLL.dll")`?  You probably meant `L"..\\Debug\\LoadDLL\\LoadDLL.dll"` without the parentheses for a wide-char string.  I'm not sure how that compiles unless you created an `L` macro?  The `_T(x)` macro expands to `L ## x` (in wide-char builds), by the way...